# How to show html page first line in textview as preview in list (recycler view) android?

Tags: android, html, textview

I am receiving an array of messages and each message has various properties and one of it is content property which is received like below

```
"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd\">\n<html>\n<head>\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\">\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Style-Type\" content=\"text/css\">\n<title></title>\n<meta name=\"Generator\" content=\"Cocoa HTML Writer\">\n<style type=\"text/css\">\np.p1 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; font: 11.0px '.SF UI Text'}\nspan.s1 {font-family: '.SFUIText'; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 11.00pt}\n</style>\n</head>\n<body>\n<p class=\"p1\"><span class=\"s1\">Test Ab<br>\n---------------------<br>\n</span></p>\n<p class=\"p1\"><span class=\"s1\">Verify the field </span></p>\n</body>\n</html>\n"
```

There is a list view to show all messages and detail view to show the description, in detail view I have implemented web view to show the content above, renders fine. In list view, I need to show the only first line of above content as a preview.

I believe using web view for every list item is dangerous plus there are items other than this to show in the list as well and the problem is because above content is an entire webpage instead of simple HTML tag (in case of for eg. Simple paragraph enclosure tag it works fine).

I tried HTMLTextview library and setText(Html.fromHtml()) method on textview too, but I am getting

```
   p.p1 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; font: 11.0px '.SF UI Text'}
```

as first line currently.

Let me know how can I accomplish showing only first line as a preview.

Comment: Please check my answer If it works for you then let me know If It not then let me modify for you.

Comment: Actually, we ended up changing server response to not have a page and <P> tag's only.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the html tag or id or class of each first line to preview, maybe [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/download) can help u to do what you want.

first [parse the html](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/parse-document-from-string)

```
String html = "<html><head><title>First parse</title></head>"
  + "<body><p>Parsed HTML into a doc.</p></body></html>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
```

then
[Finding elements](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/dom-navigation)

```
getElementById(String id)
getElementsByTag(String tag)
getElementsByClass(String className)
getElementsByAttribute(String key) (and related methods)
```

like

```
Element content = doc.getElementById("content");
```

and finally `content.text()` will give you what you are looking for.

Comment: @Learner_Programmer did it help?

Answer (score 1):

If you want content from the given link then I have written code. It's a temporary solution I mean I have tested for given link. Note It will work only for getting content from meta tag.

add in gradle, dependency: implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.3'

```
String html = "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd\">\n<html>\n<head>\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\">\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Style-Type\" content=\"text/css\">\n<title></title>\n<meta name=\"Generator\" content=\"Cocoa HTML Writer\">\n<style type=\"text/css\">\np.p1 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; font: 11.0px '.SF UI Text'}\nspan.s1 {font-family: '.SFUIText'; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 11.00pt}\n</style>\n</head>\n<body>\n<p class=\"p1\"><span class=\"s1\">Test Ab<br>\n---------------------<br>\n</span></p>\n<p class=\"p1\"><span class=\"s1\">Verify the field </span></p>\n</body>\n</html>\n";

Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements e = document.select("meta");
for (int i = 0; i<e.size(); i++ ) {

    Log.e("element",e.get(i).toString());
    // E/element: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    // E/element: <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
    // E/element: <meta name="Generator" content="Cocoa HTML Writer">

    if(e.get(i).attr("content").contains("text/")){

    }else {
        Log.e("content", e.get(i).attr("content"));
        //output: Cocoa HTML Writer
    }
}
```